# making multiple c# file for one asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

For my project(in asp.net) i wrote near 1000 lines of c# code for one asp.net page.It includes so many functions.The problem is,it is going complicated while i am writing more codes on one page.How can i make multiple c# files for one asp.net page?? I tried by adding new class in VS2008.But calling a function from one file to other is making error(item is not present in current file).How can i do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial classes will allow you to split your large class over many files. However, I would suggest that is not the ideal solution.

- You could create other classes that
  your page uses to perform a lot of
  its functionality.
- You could move some of the
  functionality into UserControls.
- You could move some shared
  functionality into a master page and
  then have multiple pages to perform
  individual tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can move some of your code into a separate `partial class` file, more likely a page that long means you should move some of your functions out of the codebehind (.aspx.cs) file into a separate code (.cs) file.

There must be some code on that page you'll find handy on others.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you have code in another file just give it a namespace and include it in the original page.

I.e.

Newclass.cs
    namespace myapp.functions
    {
    //code to include.
    }

Page.aspx.cs
    using myapp.functions;
    // now you can use them

Answer (score 0):

While I see why everyone is suggesting using partial classes, they only provide physical separation of code in separate files. I think your problem here is not the separation of the code itself, but rather splitting your functionality in components.

If there's functionality in a page that is logically grouped together, why not extract it in an ASP.NET control, expose events in this control and have the code + functionality grouped logically? This would add a bit of more effort required, but would be much, much cleaner and easily maintained. Also, if you decide to reuse some part of the page, it would be copy-paste hell if the functionality is contained as code in a page and not a control.